Finding Annihilation Operator in Space of Hermite Polynomials
This inquiry is related to my previously asked question entitled 'Proof of the Orthogonality of Hermite Polynomials' upon which I have defined a certain space with the following basis,
$$
\psi_n(x) = [\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} H_n(x),
$$
where,
$$
H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} (\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}.
$$
Now, I'm willing to prove that there exists an annihilation operator in this space called $\hat{a}$ as such,
$$
\hat{a} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\dfrac{d}{dx} + x].
$$
The procedure is quite easy to follow; to prove the aforementioned statement, I have to prove,
$$
\hat{a} \psi_n(x) = \sqrt{n} \psi_{n-1}(x),
$$
upon which I may verify the first statement (i.e., there exists such operator as $\hat{a}$). In the derivation process, there's a particular part that's causing me some frustration.
Step-by-step Procedure
$$
\hat{a}\psi_n(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\dfrac{d}{dx} + x]\cdot [\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} (-1)^n e^{x^2} (\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}.
$$
For simplicity, I'd like to name all the coefficients as $\dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}$. Henceforth,
$$
\hat{a}\psi_n(x) = \dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}[\dfrac{d}{dx} + x]\cdot[e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} (\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}]
$$
Now, forget the coefficient for a moment and let us derive the brackets:
$$
xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}+xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}-2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}+\dots
$$
In this section, I actually treated $(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}$ as a product and wanted to take the derivative (that's why we got $-2x\dots$). But I do not know whether I should do the following,
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} ((\dfrac{d}{dx})^n) = (\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n+1}, or, \dfrac{d}{dx} ((\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n}) = n(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}.
$$
In either case, I cannot go any further.
Important update:
I've tried to contemplate the problem for a while. It seems the following approach is correct. But I cannot deduce the final result.
If I consider $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n = n(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1}$, the derivations becomes,
$$
xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}+xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}-2xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n e^{-x^2}+ne^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} e^{-x^2}.
$$
The first, second, and third expression cancel out. Here is the remaining of the derivation,
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat{a}\psi_n(x) &= \dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}}[ne^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} e^{-x^2}],\\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}} n e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} e^{-x^2},\\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{\sqrt{2}} n e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} e^{-x^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, I write the whole expression (notice that I factor $-1$ out of $(-1)^n$ in order to get $-(-1)^{n-1}$),
$$
\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{2}}[\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} 2^n n!}]^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} (-)(-1)^{n-1} e^{x^2} (\dfrac{d}{dx})^{n-1} e^{-x^2}
$$
I have successfully made $H_{n-1}(x)$, but here is the problem; in the forthcoming derivation, the $\sqrt{2}$ must not be in the denominator but in numerator -- so that I can bring it to the main coefficient and cancel out one of the $2$ in the denominator to get $2^{n-1}$. Also, by entering $n$ in the square root, I'll get $n^2$ and I'm able to cancel out $n$ in the factorial to get $(n-1)!$. So far so good.
The Problem is, I get the final result as,
$$
\hat{a}\psi_n(x) = -\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}(x),
$$
which contradicts the assumption. Besides, I've changed the coefficient of annihilation operator which is wrong. I must not change the operator.
However, by rules of the Hermite polynomials, one person answered my question meticulously and got the correct results. But what is the problem with my approach?

are you asking about the rules of differentiation or about Hermite polynomials?

@user619894 I'm asking about the differentiation problem.

Then maybe you could simplify your question and ask directly about the issue, without details about Hermite polynomials and annhilation operators. If I read you correctly, you want to know how to apply $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{d}{dx})^n$ to a general function.

You have :
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{a}\psi_n(x) 
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} + x\right) c_n e^{-x^2/2} H_n(x), \quad\mathrm{with}\quad c_n = (2^nn!\sqrt{\pi})^{-1/2} \\
   &= \frac{c_n}{\sqrt{2}} \left(-xe^{-x^2/2}H_n(x) + e^{-x^2/2}H_n'(x) + xe^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)\right) \\
   &= \frac{c_n}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot 2ne^{-x^2/2}H_{n-1}(x) \\
   &= \sqrt{n}\,c_{n-1}e^{-x^2/2}H_{n-1}(x) \\
   &= \sqrt{n}\,\psi_{n-1}(x)
\end{align}
$$
where we used the fact that $H_n'(x) = 2nH_{n-1}(x)$. The latter property may be itself proven as follows.
Since $H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} \partial_x^n e^{-x^2}$, one gets $H_n'(x) = 2xH_n(x) - H_{n+1}(x)$ after differentiation. Now, the term $H_{n+1}(x)$ contains the expression $\partial_x^{n+1} e^{-x^2} = \partial_x^n (-2xe^{-x^2})$. The $n^\mathrm{th}$ derivative of a product may be expanded thanks to the general Leibniz rule, as done below :
$$
\partial_x^n (-2xe^{-x^2}) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \partial_x^k(-2x) \,\partial_x^{n-k}e^{-x^2} = -2x\partial_x^ne^{-x^2} - 2n\partial_x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}
$$
Note that only the first two terms of the expansion don't vanish. Recollecting all the different factors, we end up with the desired relation in the end, namely $H_n'(x) = 2nH_{n-1}(x)$.

Thank you for your answer @Abezhiko It's quite funny that I cannot deduce your result by direct differential derivation. Could you help me in this regard?

@HoomanPuyandeh  I guess you didn't treat the expression $\partial_x^n(e^{-x^2})$ correctly.  It seems you applied an erroneous simplification when stating $\partial_x^{n+1} \equiv n\partial_x^{n-1}$. I've edited my answer to tackle your problem.
